# Property "CDbCriteria.0" is not defined in yii

Tags: php, yii

Below is my controller code having the following function;

```
 public function actionUpdateJob($id)
    {

         if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $id=$_GET['id'];
        }
         var_dump($id);

     $model= UpdateJob::model()->find (array(
                                             'select'=>'posted_by','title','key_skills','condition'=>'id="$id',
                                             'limit'=>1,));
  $params = array('model' => $model,'id' => $id);

  $this->render('update',$params);

    }
```

While executing, I am getting error

```
Property "CDbCriteria.0" is not defined .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `select =>` has to be array with `['posted_by', 'title', 'key_skills']`

And your condition is wrong. Use 
`id=:id` and in params add: `..., ':id' => $id`

Comment: like this ?:   $model= UpdateJob::model()->find (array(
                                             'select'=>array([ 'posted_by','title','key_skills']),'condition'=>'id=:id',
                                             'limit'=>1,));

Comment: @saji no, like "$model= UpdateJob::model()->find (array( 'select'=>array( 'posted_by','title','key_skills'),'condition'=>'id=:id', 'limit'=>1,));", no need for '[]' in array.

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
'condition'=>'id="$id',
```

To:

```
'condition'=>'id="$id"',
```

You have missed quotation mark.